# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object not found: JNDI implementation returned null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, datasource

I am using jboss 5.1. I am trying to get database connection using data source.
I am getting this exception

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object with [java:/monitords]
>   not found: JNDI implementation returned null

my **`context-datasource.xml`** file look like that

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

 
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:/monitords"></property>
 
 </bean>
 

</beans>
```

My **`web.xml`** file look like that.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
                         "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/spring-batch-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
  
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
  <display-name>MyController</display-name>
  <servlet-class>com.varun.job.controller.MyController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyController/StartBatch</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyController/StopBatch</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 <resource-ref>
  <description>My DataSource</description>
  <res-ref-name>monitords</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
   
</web-app>
```

Bellow is the data source which is inside jboss5.1 deploy folder

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<datasources>
 
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>monitords</jndi-name>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip and path</connection-url>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
 <min-pool-size>25</min-pool-size> 
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>     
 <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>    
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
  </local-tx-datasource>
  
</datasources>
```

dont worry about the `<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip and path</connection-url>` I have changed it for security purpose. The details are correct for sure. I have checked it with SQL developer.

Can any one tell me What is wrong with my configuration Why I am getting the above exception.

Comment: In the datasource xml, have you tried putting <jndi-name> as java:/monitords ?

Comment: @bmarkham Can you please make it more clear I am new to spring I dont know about <jndi-name> tag

Comment: haha so am I.  In your data source xml folder. Change ` <jndi-name>monitords</jndi-name>` to ` <jndi-name>java:/monitords</jndi-name>` and see what happens. It's in the very last code snippet you posted.

Comment: When I changed to `<jndi-name>java:/monitords</jndi-name>` I get this exception `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: monitords not bound
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)`